# What is wrong with my integral solving

Tags: integration

Consider the integral

$$\int{ \frac{x^2+2x+8}{(x^2-2x)(x^2+4)}}dx$$

I simplify it to $$\int\frac{x^2+2x+8}{x(x-2)(x^2+4)}$$

Then I try to solve it in sum of partial fraction which gives me

$$\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x-2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+4}$$

Then when applying to terms I get

$$\frac{(A+B+C)x^3+(D-2A-C)x^2+(4A+4B-2)x-8A}{x(x-2)(x^2+4)}$$

But then I am unable to solve the variable so I'm pretty sure my method is wrong, but can't figure out why...

What am-I missing ?

Comment: Your method is correct and now you just have to solve the simultaneous equations.  I haven't checked the details of your working.

Comment: You have to compare the coefficients. This gives you $A+B+C=0, D-2A-C=1,4A+4B-2D=2,-8A=8$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct numerator should read:  $$(A+B+C)x^3 + (D - 2A - \color{red}2C)x^2 + (4A + 4B - 2\color{red}D)x - 8A.$$

That said, I should point out that a slightly easier method of solution would involve what is sometimes called the "cover-up" method.  Basically, substitute the values of $x$ for which the denominator is zero:  so for example, to get the coefficient $A$, let $x = 0$ to obtain $(0-2)(0^2 + 4)A = 0^2 + 2(0) + 8$, or $A = -1$.  Similarly, let $x = 2$ to obtain $(2)(2^2 + 4)B = 2^2 + 2(2) + 8$, or $B = 1$.  That gives you two of the four coefficients, making the rest easier to solve.

Comment: $-(1/2) ArcTan[x/2] + 2 ArcTanh[1 - x]$

Comment: @heropup Thanks for your answer, can you confirm that C would be equal to 1 and D equal to 19 ?

Comment: @ProgrammerJeff  The solution set is $(A,B,C,D) = (-1, 1, 0, -1)$.  This is because once we establish $A = -1$, $B = 1$, then the $x^3$ coefficient is $A+B+C = 0$; hence $C = 0$.  Then comparing the coefficient of $x$, we get $4(-1)+4(1)-2D = 2$, hence $D = -1$.

Comment: Finally understood, thanks :)